# ajax append causes javascript to be executed multiple times

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I've created a dynamic table in PHP, where every image in a row has a specific url in the ID.

For example:

When a user clicks on this image, it executes an action. This works fine.

Afterwards, in the second ajax, it's supposed to reload the colorbox with the previous url. This also works, however, the javascript seems to be loaded again (with the new values though)?

```
$('#cboxLoadedContent img[alt="markmessage"]').live('click', function(){
var returnurl = "<?php echo $_SESSION['returnpage']; ?>";
var markurl = $(this).attr('id');
alert(markurl);

// Do the action
$.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url: markurl,
    cache:false
});

// Reload colorbox again with previous contenturl.
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: returnurl,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cboxLoadedContent').empty();
                $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
                $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').hide();
        },
        success: function(data) {              
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').empty(); 
                $('#cboxLoadedContent').append(data);
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Is there any way to PREVENT the javascript from being re-appended to the colorbox? I've tried a few methods (like removing it with DOM), but nothing seems to work...

The javascript may NOT be disabled, it's supposed to process a new url afterwards...

Comment: Are you preventing the default action when you click on the link? Also I `live` has be deprecated, use `on` instead, also instead of empty and append you can just use html to replace the content.

Comment: I've edited the code as you suggested, however, the problem still exists. I added 'markmessage' as a class for every image generated...

`$(document).on("click", "img.markmessage", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();`

Comment: `.live` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use `.on`, `one` or `.delegate` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the simple [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event binding. Here you only bind it to the selected elements, not to new appended elements. If you want the event to be fired only once, use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution:
`$(document).one("click", "img.markmessage", function() {`

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `live` to `one` in first line: 
`$('#cboxLoadedContent img[alt="markmessage"]').one('click', function(){`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of jQuery you are using, but `live()` is deprecated as of 1.7, you might want to try using `on()`.